# TestNG : I want to login only once,execute all the testcases ,logout of the application and then should close the browser

Tags: selenium, testng, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am implementing hybrid framework i am posting the code below

```
public class BaseClass {

    public WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters({"browser","component"})
    public void launchBrowser(String browser,String component) throws Exception{

        if(browser.equals("firefox")){

            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            BasePage basePageObject = new BasePage(driver);

            if(null!=component) {

                if(component.equals("Operations")){

                    driver.get(propertyDataObj.getOdUrl());
                    System.out.println("odusername---"+propertyDataObj.getOdUserName());
                    System.out.println("odpassword---"+propertyDataObj.getOdPassword());
                    basePageObject.loginToOd(odUserName, odPassword);

                }
```

In the above code I have used `@BeforeTest` in-order to login to the application only once but when I run the framework, only first testcase gets executed and I am getting no such window found exception and the execution is getting terminated.

Comment: How you are running your test case? Please provide your testng xml file.

Comment: And where are located your tests? In the same class or another one? Could share them too?

Answer (score 0):

I have to do the following:

`@BeforeClass` - start browser and log in

`@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun=true)` - navigate to main page

`@Test` - do what you want

`@AfterClass` - close browser

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `@BeforeClass` annotation so that the part of code which you want to execute once i.e. Login to your application executes before any other method of the class.

After executing all the test using `@Test`, you can use `@AfterClass` to close your browser (also log out of the application in case you need that type of functionality)

For more testng annotations, you can refer the link: http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-introduction/

Answer (score 0):

First Open Browser Code '@BeforeClass'

Login to Application '@BeforeMethod'

Perform actions
@Test
@Test`Any Action code`
@Test

Logout Application  `@AfterMethod`
Close Browser  '@AfterClass'